# How to swap two commands in bash?

Tags: bash, alias

Say I have command `A` and command `B` but I want `B` to run when I type `A` and vice versa. I've tried

```
alias A='B'
alias B='A'
```

But this doesn't seem to work for some reason.

How do I do this?

EDIT:

Command `B` has actually been defined as a function in my `.bashrc`, so

```
alias A='command B'
alias B='command A'
```

doesn't work as suggested.

I guess I could update the question to say that `A` and `B` could also be functions defined in bash.

Comment: `alias A='command B' B='command A'`. Or, if you're *certain* that the only reference you want to avoid is the alias you've just defined, then `alias A=\\B B=\\A`.

Comment: Option 2 worked, this could have been posted as an answer, thanks! Option 1 didn't work, I think it is because `B` is actually a function defined in my `.bashrc`. I don't understand what you mean by "the only reference you want to avoid is the alias" - could you explain that further please?

Comment: I guess you *did* update the question to say that... haha.

Comment: Oh yeah so I did :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can get explicit about the way the shell goes about locating commands in a few different ways. You can use...

```
command command_name
```

...to instruct the shell only to invoke the *command_name* if it is a `$PATH`d executable. This is important in cases like yours because, when you've finished `alias A` refers to `alias B` which refers to `alias A` usually something like 20 times before the `alias` expansion quits recursing - and which lands you right back where you started. If you wanted to definitely only invoke a `$PATH`d executable `B` when calling `A` and vice versa you can do...

```
alias A='command B' B='command A'
```

...which should avoid even calling functions named `A` or `B`. Otherwise - because the shell will not expand a quoted `alias` as an `alias` but will still call a function even if its *command_name* is quoted you can quote `A` and `B` in the definitions like...

```
alias A=\\B B=\\A
```

Ok, so it doesn't recurse twenty times. I could swear I had read that in some `man` page, but I guess it is at least not true of either `bash` or `ksh` *(having tested only either of them so far)*. It, in fact, recurses only twice:

```
n=0
A(){ echo not B; n=0; }
B(){ echo not A; n=0; }
alias A='echo "$((n+=1))";B' B='echo "$((n+=1))";A'
```

If I do the above and do...

```
A
```

...in `bash` it prints:

```
1
2
not B
```

I guess this is relevant to this from the `bash` manual:

- The first word of the replacement text is tested for aliases, but a word that is identical to an alias being expanded is not expanded a second time. This means that one may alias `ls` to `ls -F`, for instance, and `bash` does not try to recursively expand the replacement text.

I had read that before, but I didn't think it would test all expansions leading up to the current expansion when doing so - I figured it would only apply to the latest expansion in the chain. Anyway, that appears to be why.

I did note some interesting behavior otherwise though. After I had already declared both the aliases and the functions I went to rerun the commands, but with a little less intervening white space - like this:

```
A(){ echo not B; }; B(){ echo not A; }; A; B
```

...and that did...

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
not B
7
8
not A
```

Which means that the shell substituted the alias contents in for the function name - which is not a position one might normally expect an expansion to occur - did the `echo`s and *still* redefined then executed the functions.

Comment: Nice analysis, turns out the expansion rules are quite complicated. I guess you have to careful with circular aliases! Maybe one day I'll look at the code for alias expansion and post a more general explanation.

Comment: Ok the solution has worked fine so far, I have been using `alias man=\\vman vman=\\man` where `man` is just the ordinary man pages and `vman` is a custom defined function in my `.bashrc`. When I run `source ~/.bashrc`, I get the following error: `bash: '\man': not a valid identifier`. This error doesn't appear when opening a new terminal. Why does this happen?

Comment: @texasflood - I would guess you are quoting the assignment in that case? Like `alias 'vman=\\man'` maybe? If not I can't say for sure, but you can get a better idea by doing `set -vx` at the top of your environment file.

Comment: Ok, the output from that produces `bash: '\man': not a valid identifier` right after the definition of `vman()`, and then I have the alias, `alias man=\\vman vman=\\man`, and then it seems to add the alias as per the line below:
`++ alias 'man=\vman' 'vman=\man'`

Comment: And no, I'm not quoting the assignment. You can see the output here: https://gist.github.com/texasflood/988f70634bc749e38f77

Comment: @texasflood - ahh! I get it. You're sourcing your environment file - so those aliases are already defined when you do. It's exactly what I mentioned here in the answer - the alias is substituting even in the the function definition command - so you're doing `vman()...` but *really* doing `${contents of alias vman -> man} \man()...`

Comment: It's good to know there wasn't actually a problem with the alias itself!