# grom() keyword in bash throws unexpected '(' token

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias, function, profile

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting the error in my `.bash_profile`

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

when I use the keyword `grom()` for my function. I wanted to create a bash function that will just automatically rebase my master branch with origin

```
# git status
alias gs='git status'

# git stash list
alias gsl='git stash list'  

grom() {
  branch_name="$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)"
  git fetch && git rebase origin/master && git checkout master && git rebase origin/master && git checkout $branch_name
}

# git stash apply. must append stash@{num}
alias gsa="git stash apply"
```

When I change the name of the function, it compiles fine. I couldn't find `grom` as a keyword so I'm not sure what the issue is. If I rename the function to anything else like `git-rom` or even something like `groms`, it compiles fine. Is there some special keywords that do not work? This is on Mac OS X.

Comment: If you're using `bash`, you may have better luck declaring it as `function grom() { … }`.  Another possibility is that there is an open-parenthesis in the output of your first `git` command; try `git checkout "$branch_name"` as your last chained command, which may get you a `git` error, but at least you'd know what needs fixing.  (Sorry, I'm not yet a `git` guru)

Comment: You should probably show people the immediately preceding lines, too.

Comment: @AdamKatz Adding function in front seemed to fix the issue. I tried the latter option and I still got the error. Very intriguing considering I have other functions in my bash-profile that do not require `function` in front. If you want to add that as an answer, I'd be willing to accept it. I'm still curious why it does this though. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JdeBP I added what was around the function for reference. I do not think the things around it are the issue though considering different names worked like `groms()` and `git-rom()`.

Comment: Add `set -x` to see what exactly is executed.

Comment: @michas do you mean in the function? This is happening when I run `source ./bash_profile` to update my `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you've got one of `grom()` or `gs[ail]` also defined as alias/functions, right? If you declare a function with the same name as an `alias` the alias will expand out to `${alias}(){` and you'll very likely get the error *unexpected token `(`*

Comment: @mikeserv I think I found the issue and you're right. I quit my terminal and reloaded it. I used to have an `alias` of `grom` but not anymore so I didn't think that was the issue. Perhaps it was caching my old `.bash_profile`? Either way thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `bash`, you may have better luck declaring it as:

```
function grom() { … }
```

(Note: `function` *will not work* in strict POSIX shells like `dash`!)

---

[@aug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79739/aug) suggested (via edits to this answer) that this is due to a conflicting alias (or, less plausibly, a builtin that somehow got defined).

The reserved word **function** either alters the loading order to preempt the collision (aliases expand during function definition) or else avoids the issue by disabling bash's *posix mode* (which may allow overriding a builtin).

From the `bash(1)` man page:

> Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the function is executed, because a function definition is itself a compound command. As a consequence, aliases defined in a function are not available until after that function is executed.

If you have a conflicting alias, you can try `unalias grom` before sourcing `.bash_profile` (it isn't necessary to add to that file unless you're still defining that conflicting alias) to clear your past experiments.  Alternatively, launch a new terminal for a clean start.

Comment: I added an edit the answer of what I think may have been the issue.

Comment: @mikeserv, I've removed the link to your [related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187530/how-to-swap-two-commands-in-bash/187534#187534) because it's not as obviously relevant and your citation from the man page is preferable.  I've also credited you and aug in my answer.  Both of you have helped answer *why* this works and you deserve credit (I've also given your comments +1).  Thanks!