# How can a subshell return data in a variable (not file) and output distinct logs at the same time?

Tags: logs, io-redirection, subshell

Say I've got the following javascript:

```javascript
    const something = doSomething();
    
    function doSomething() {
        console.log("About to do something");
        
        const a = doSomethingElse();
        if (a == "dog") {
            console.log("Worked");
            console.log("Now let's do xyz");
            return "cat";
        } else {
            console.log("failed for some reason");
            return "horse";
        }
    }
    
    function doSomethingElse() {
        console.log("About to do more");
        console.log("Done doing more stuff");
        
        return "dog";
    }
```

How can we achieve this in bash ? And I want to view the logs in real time, not store them in a file for later ? I'm thinking about something like the following, but then all gets mixed together, plus the return keyword in bash serves other purposes and can't accept strings.

```bsh
    something=$(doSomething);
    
    function doSomething() {
        console_log "About to do something";
        
        a=$(doSomethingElse);
        if [[$a = "dog"]]; then
            console_log "Worked";
            console_log "Now let's do xyz";
            echo "cat"; # Wish I could do return "cat" ...
        else
            console_log "failed for some reason";
            echo "horse"; # Wish I could do return "horse" ...
        fi;
    }
    
    function doSomethingElse() {
        console_log "About to do more";
        console_log "Done doing more stuff";
        
        echo 'dog'; #Wish I could do return "dog" ...
    }
    
    function console_log() {
        #Is echo the right thing, or tee, or something else ?
        echo $1;
    }
```

Isn't there multiple output streams to achieve this ? Or, is there an alternative to $() to assign variables ? I have tried to play with tee, &*, &? and 3>1 stuff and I can't make sense of all this... :(

I have bash 4.2.46 under CentOS 7.9

thanks for your help :)

Comment: @fra-san sorry, it's not to port JS code, I was trying to find a way to explain what I'm trying to do using non-shell languages. ibuprofen pointed out to printf with >&2, which is exactly what I needed. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be OK:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -

doSomething() {
    print_err "About to do something"

    a="$(doSomethingElse)"
    if [[ "$a" = "dog" ]]; then
        print_err "Worked"
        print_err "Now let's do xyz"
        printf '%s' "cat"
    else
        print_err "failed for some reason"
        printf '%s' "horse"
    fi
}

doSomethingElse() {
    print_err "About to do more";
    print_err "Done doing more stuff";
    printf '%s' 'dog'
}

print_err() {
    # Print to stderr as we do this in functions
    # that print result to stdout
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
}

something="$(doSomething)"
# Making it readonly would be somewhat similar to const
readonly something

printf '%s\n' "$something"
```

Needed:

- Move `something="$(doSomething)"` after declaration of `doSomething`. Bash executes statements on a read-by basis. (Why you also can use `exit` to abort a script.) In JavaScript the code is read, compiled and run.
- In your `if test` you need space between the brackets and the arguments.
  In general:
  [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/140633)
- You have to redirect non-data to `stderr` on echo, as in `>&2` else all output is assigned to variables such as `a`.
  [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/70963/140633) 
  [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/140633)

In general:

- `printf`: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/140633)
- Quote. Always quote. Better to quote once to often then once to few. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/140633
- `function` not needed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917018/3342816 , [grom() keyword in bash throws unexpected '(' token](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192518/140633)

Beyond that, replacing `[[` with `[` would make it `sh` compliant. [What does it mean to be "sh compatible"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145522/140633)

Also look into scopes of variables. [Is there a way to make the local command work portably to dash ksh bash and zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539680/140633)

As in, you *could have*, done:

```bsh
set_something() {
    something='cat'
}

set_something
printf 'something="%s"\n' "$something"
```

---

#### Streams

JavaScript does not work with streams, shell does. Simplified it:

- `read` from `stdin`, file-descriptor `0` (standard in)
- `write` to `stdout`, file-descriptor `1` (standard out)
- `write` to `stderr`, file-descriptor `2` (standard error)

Beyond that one can open new, read / write files etc.

Might of interest [How portable are /dev/stdin, /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36403/140633)

---

#### Return values.

Bash functions does not "return" strings. When one do:

```bsh
foo="$(some command)"
```

one assign the standard output of `some command` to `foo`. If one do not change the redirect of *non-data* prints in your code, you can see this by:

```bsh
# In doSomething():
    printf 'a="%s"\n' "$a" >&2

# At end:
printf '"%s"\n' "$something"
```

You would get:

```
a="About to do more
Done doing more stuff
dog"
something="About to do something
failed for some reason
horse"
```

As you see, the entire output is assigned.

After *"fix"* one *could* capture both `stdout` and `stderr` by redirecting stderr to stdout:

```bsh
foo="$(some command 2>&1)"
```

---

#### Exit code

Shell functions do, however, have exit codes, just like any program. If not explicitly returning a value, it's the exit status of the last command executed in that function. `0` is OK, anything else is considered an error in tests.

Simple example:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash -

foo() {
    printf 'I am foo\n'
    return 1
}
greetings() {
    if [ "$1" = "hi" ]; then
        printf 'Hello\n'
    else
        printf 'I do not know what to do with %s\n' "$1"
        return 12
    fi
}
if foo; then
    printf 'OK\n'
else
    printf 'FAIL\n'
fi

printf '\n## Try greetings "yo":\n'
greetings yo
ecode=$?
printf 'greetings() returned %d\n' "$ecode"

printf '\n## Try greetings "hi":\n'
greetings hi
ecode=$?
printf 'greetings() returned %d\n' "$ecode"
```

Result:

```
I am foo
FAIL

## Try greetings "yo":
I do not know what to do with yo
greetings() returned 12

## Try greetings "hi":
Hello
greetings() returned 0
```

#### Some help by `shellcheck`

Not fool-proof but can be great help with linting scripts.

You can use it as a command line tool, [paste code online](https://www.shellcheck.net/), or incorporate it into your editor.

For example if you use Vim with ALE, it picks up `shellcheck` if installed. Be aware though that packages bundled with distributions can be somewhat outdated. Ubuntu 18.04, for example, uses v0.4.6

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck

#### Shell scripts in general

Playing around with `bash` et al. can be useful for learning. Always consider what you want to do. text-processing for example is almost always better done with other tools. Then one can use shell-scripts to glue it all together. Use pipes etc. - part of the power of the unices. Here under for example `sort`, `join`, `cut`, `tr`, `paste`, `uniq`, `find`, `grep`, `cat`, `date`, `tail`, `head`, `xargs`, `wc`, `fold`, `column`, `paste`, and so on.

Interactive shell scripts has it use as well as expanding your shell with various functionality.

With more advanced data-types and complexity use things like `perl`, `python`, and a wide range of others or even `c`. `c` is in general a very nice way to learn about the system at a lower level.

`awk`, `sed` etc. are also very powerful and useful for processing text where `awk` is the easier to learn.

Comment: Wow that's an amazing explanation :O I've tried and it worked ! many thanks.
Now, I'm trying to have my whole script die when any nested sub shell "throws an error", but part of the higher shells keep on running. I've seen something like:
 
 PROCESS="$$";
 set -E;
 trap '[ "$?" -ne 77 ] || kill -10 $PROCESS';
 
And do exit 77; in sub shells, but it doesn't work.
For now I'm doing kill -9 0; ...

Comment: @mboisvert-bravad heh, I do not quite like it myself and was about to delete it, but hope you get some out of it. A bit too much all over the place perhaps.

Comment: sorry my reply got cut, I've made edits to it :P Your time is really appreciated

Comment: @mboisvert-bravad Depends on what you are doing and how you exit / abort. At top level you simply do for example `exit 1` to abort script with error code 1. You might want `set -e`, or  `set -E; trap 'exit 1' ERR` https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html - in general, if you do not figure it out write a sample script and post a question. There is a lot of Q/A on the topic already as well.

Comment: "Shell functions do, however, have exit codes, just like any program. If not stated it is zero." If not explicitly returning a value, it's the exit status of the last command executed in that function, not 0.

Comment: @muru Thanks. Low quality on that statement.